# Reset @@FETCH_STATUS stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, database-cursor

How can I reset the `@@FETCH_STATUS` variable or set it to 0 in a stored procedure?

Also, can you bind FETCH_STATUS to a particular cursor?

Comment: Could you explain why this behavior would be desired? Maybe the community can solve your need in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to reproduce the [`@@FETCH_STATUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187308.aspx) issue you describe, this is once you `DECLARE` a `CURSOR` and iterate through the rows by calling `FETCH NEXT` until your `@@FETCH_STATUS = -1`.
Then even if you `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` your cursor, if you call that `CURSOR` back your `@@FETCH_STATUS = -1` and if your basing a loop condition on the `@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1`, your loop never executes.

My solution was to basically tell the `CURSOR` to go back to `FIRST`, changing the `@@FETCH_STATUS` back to `0`, then exiting. Take note that one must enable to `CURSOR` to be scrolling by adding the keyword `SCROLL` after the `CURSOR` name when you declare it.

Here's an example. I used three columns from an orderitems (items people placed orders for) table to create my cursor:

```
USE transact_Sales;

GO

DECLARE @isOrderNumber INT;
DECLARE @isOrderTotal MONEY;
DECLARE test SCROLL CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Oi.order_num, SUM(Oi.quantity@item_price) FROM orderitems AS Oi GROUP BY order_num;

OPEN test;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
FETCH NEXT FROM test INTO @isOrderNumber, @isOrderTotal
PRINT CAST(@isOrderNumber AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' '
     +CAST(@isOrderTotal AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' '
     +CAST(@@FETCH_STATUS AS VARCHAR(5))
END
FETCH FIRST FROM test INTO @isOrderNumber, @isOrderTotal

CLOSE test;
DEALLOCATE test;
```

These are the results:

```
20005 149.87 0  
20006 55.00 0  
20007 1000.00 0  
20008 125.00 0  
20009 38.47 0  
20009 38.47 -1
```

The cursor can be run over and over and will product the same results each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset it by reading a cursor which is not at the end of a table.

Comment: Another related question I have is can you bind FETCH_STATUS to a particular cursor?

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the cursor and then Open the cursor again.

```
DECLARE @IDs int
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR(SELECT ID FROM Table)
OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @IDs
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    --Do your work(First loop)
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @IDs
END
CLOSE MyCursor
--Run the cursor again
OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursorINTO @IDs
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    --Other work (Second loop)
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @IDs
END
CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

Answer (score 1):

An old thread I know but an answer found elsewhere that worked for me was:

```
WHILE (1 = 1) 
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @somevar
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0) BREAK
    -- do stuff here
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't:

> @@FETCH_STATUS (Transact-SQL)
>
> Returns the status **of the last
>   cursor** FETCH statement **issued
>   against any cursor** currently opened
>   by the connection.

So basically it's not bound to any cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you have a @@FETCH_STATUS *immediately* after a FETCH, so why would you want to reset it?

Try to store its result in a temporary variable if you do not evaluate immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break cursor You can use [BREAK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181271.aspx)
But this only only replace function from 0 to 1.

```
fetch next
While @@fetch_Status = 0
begin

if (my condition)
 break
fetch next ;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had what I thought was a need to reset my cursor.
I was doing some testing with cursors and I kept coming back with a @@fetch_status being = -1, even after I had coded a close and deallocation to the cursor I was testing.

What had happened was I had opened a global cursor in another procedure after a logical test and never closed that cursor after iterating through it.

So the Fetch was seeing the @@Fetch_status of that cursor.

Close your cursors, deallocate your cursors.